# trying to connect using dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

can i connect to server DPS from server MDC using dblink
so i already create dblink from MDC to JKT, JKT to DPS, and DPS to JKT

[dblink image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJYPm.png)

i already try this syntax:
select * from (select * from salary@XE.DPS.ID.ORACLE.COM;)@XE.JKT.ID.ORACLE.COM;

but I get an error
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 25 Column: 56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same network, isn't it? If so, you can create direct database link from DPS to MDC.

---

You would need a "bridge" if databases involved in DPS and MDC aren't "compatible" - for example, database versions difference is too high and you can't establish direct connection. Something like this (note that the following example is just for illustration purposes. Maybe I used wrong database versions, but this is just for you to get the idea what I'm talking about): you're running Oracle 12c on MDC and old Oracle 8i on DPS; then you'd need JKT which runs 10g and is able to communicate with both 8i and 12c.

---

As of syntax you used: that won't work, I'm afraid - you can't "embed" queries like that. As of error you got, it is about semi-colon:

```
select * 
from (select * 
      from salary@XE.DPS.ID.ORACLE.COM;   <-- this semi-colon
     )@XE.JKT.ID.ORACLE.COM;
```

If you really need JKT in between, create a view in that schema (view selects data from `salary` table located in DPS database):

```
-- this is on JKT database
create or replace view v_salary as
  select * from salary@xe.dps.id.oracle.com;
```

and then access it from MDC:

```
-- this is on MDC database
select *
from v_salary@XE.JKT.ID.ORACLE.COM
```

Comment: I'm using the same version on all databases (11g), and they're all on the same network. This is for my coursework, so I'm afraid that I might not be able to create a dblink between MDC and DPS because it doesn't match the topology.